# Python Pandas Replicate and update DataFrame Rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like:

```
raw_data = {
    'name': ['Name1', 'Name2'],
    'zone': ['zone1','zone2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['value','name','zone'])

print(df)

  value   name   zone
0   NaN  Name1  zone1
1   NaN  Name2  zone2
```

I have to update the DataFrame with a list so that each row is duplicated with each value from the list:

```
update_values = ['a1', 'a2']

# The desired dataframe looks like:

  value   name   zone
0   a1    Name1  zone1
1   a1    Name2  zone2
2   a2    Name1  zone1
3   a2    Name2  zone2
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with parameter `keys` - it create `MultiIndex`, so necessary [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column:

```
df = (pd.concat([df.drop('value', axis=1)] * len(update_values), keys=update_values)
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .rename_axis('value')
        .reset_index())
print(df)
  value   name   zone
0    a1  Name1  zone1
1    a1  Name2  zone2
2    a2  Name1  zone1
3    a2  Name2  zone2
```

Or repeat values by [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
update_values = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']

df1 = pd.concat([df] * len(update_values), ignore_index=True)
df1['value'] = np.tile(update_values, len(df))
print(df1)
  value   name   zone
0    a1  Name1  zone1
1    a2  Name2  zone2
3    a3  Name1  zone1
4    a1  Name2  zone2
5    a2  Name1  zone1
6    a3  Name2  zone2
```